# How do I make my cloud run link more secure?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

When I make a GCP cloud run instance anyone can to that link. I am using it for an API for my website. I do not want Joe Blow opening <kbd>F12</kbd> and following the HTTP requests to my API. I use API keys and stuff however I want my link to be protected to only certain IP addresses or at least lock it behind a username and password. How can I do this with cloud run on GCP?

Comment: If the client browser is calling your Cloud Run service, then it is public. Using a password would not help. Modify your site's design to call Cloud Run from your server and implement Cloud Run authorization. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview

Comment: @JohnHanley Thank you so much. I think the issue comes down to me trying to use Cloud Run for my API. I think a service like App Engine with its firewalls and IP filtering would be better for the API between my website and my database.

Comment: @ZachGonzalez, is your question already resolved? If so, please post it as an answer so that other community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Run exposes a public URL by default. You can make it public (let allUsers invoke your endpoint) or restricted (only authorized user can invoke)

The problem with the second solution is that only the Google accounts (Workspace or Gmail) can be added and so restrict your user to use that type of credentials.

So, the solution is to make your API public. You can implement security mechanism in it to software control the authN and authZ of your user, but you aren't protected against DDOS attacks.

Therefore, [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor) enters in the game. You have to create a Load Balancer and to put your Cloud Run service as backend of it. Then activate Cloud Armor. You will be able to check the IP source of the requester, but also to protect your service against attacks.

Answer (score 0):

- You can make your cloud run service internal and then attach it to a load-balancing service this way you can define a good link for your API.
- While you are creating a load balancer you have to create a backend service for your API which you can make more secure.
- By using either Identity Aware proxy another good gcp service.
- Or you can attach some cloud armor policies to that API.

If you know about these stuff that is good still you wanted a comprehensive answer just reply back to this post and I will try to write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I am considering is that we need to set the ingress settings to 'all' with authentication enabled. This way, service-to-service traffic will utilize GCP internal traffic, as both the source and destination are within GCP, using the default Cloud Run URL. However, the problem arises because setting ingress to 'all' exposes the URL to the internet, if we use LB/Cloud armor then traffic will have to route via internet